# ¬p ⊬ ⎕(p → q): Where's the mistake in my proof?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus, modal-logic

My professor noted on one of his slides that ¬p ⊬ ⎕(p → q). Intuitively, this seems correct; however, I can only prove that it is false. I suspect I've made a mistake in my proof. Where have I gone wrong?

1. ¬(¬p→⎕(p → q)), w0✓
2. ¬p ∧ ◊¬(p → q), w0✓
3. ¬p, w0
4. ◊¬(p → q), w0✓w1
5. w0Rw1
6. ¬(p → q),w1✓
7. p∧¬q, w1✓
8. p, w1
9. ¬q, w1
10. ⊥: (3.¬p w0, 5.w0Rw1, 8. p w1)

It is false that it is false that ¬p→⎕(p → q), so it is true that ¬p→⎕(p → q). If it is true that ¬p→⎕(p → q), then it cannot be the case that  ¬p ⊬ ⎕(p → q).

Comment: [Please read this.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) You've been here for almost 1.5 years and asked 53 questions, people shouldn't need to edit your posts so that they're in the right format... And what is that box symbol (the one before the opening parenthesis)?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Didn't know it was required. But yeah, it's about time I got in the habit.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi the box is the 'necessary' operator. There's a diamond (or lozenge) operator for 'possible'.

Answer (score 2):

You have $\neg p$ back in $w_0$, and $p$ in $w_1$. But *there's no contradiction between those two*, even if $w_0Rw_1$!

It is absolutely fundamental that a propositional variable can take different values at different worlds, *even if those worlds are related by the accessibility relation*.